# about the web parsing

Tags: c#

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

```
        string szURL = textBox1.Text;// "http://localhost";
        //textBox1.Text = szURL;
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
        string bodyText = "";
        Stream responseStream;
        Byte[] RecvBytes = new Byte[Byte.MaxValue];
        Int32 bytes;
        httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(szURL);
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        while (true)
        {
            bytes = responseStream.Read(RecvBytes,
            0, RecvBytes.Length);
            if (bytes <= 0) break;
            bodyText += System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RecvBytes,
            0, bytes);
        }
        //listBox1.Items.Add( bodyText);
        textBox2.Text = bodyText;

        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(bodyText, @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)", 
              RegexOptions.Singleline);

        // 2.
        // Loop over each match.
        foreach (Match m in m1)
        {
            string value = m.Groups[1].Value;
            //   LinkItem i = new LinkItem();

            // 3.
            // Get href attribute.
            Match m2 = Regex.Match(value, @"<\s*script[^>]*>(?<content>.*?)<\s*/\s*\script\s*>",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
            if (m2.Success)
            {
                listBox1.Text = m2.Groups[1].Value;
            }

            // 4.
            // Remove inner tags from text.

            string t = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s*<.*?>\s*", "",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
            // i.Text = t;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add(t);

        }




    }
```

this is my code., it is given as assignment to me.. i have to separate the content between the tags ... and the links alone from a web page... i find it very difficult,. please help me out as soon as possible..

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML is difficult and you should try using a 3rd party framework that builds a HTML DOM (preferably using some form of tokenizer) instead of using regular expressions. As you are using .NET then I would strongly suggest that you look at using the [HTMLAgility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

> It (HTML Agility Pack) is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).